# No puedo encontrar solucion para este error: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl'

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring-mvc

Hola soy nueva en Spring MVC, eh estado desarrollando un proyecto pero me ah generado un error que en realidad por mas que busco soluciones para este mismo, el problema surge al momento en que yo por mismo spring con un archivo import.sql agrego información me marca el siguiente error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl' to required type 'com.coyotes.springboot.app.models.entity.Contacto'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl' to required type 'com.coyotes.springboot.app.models.entity.Contacto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl' to required type 'com.coyotes.springboot.app.models.entity.Contacto'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl' to required type 'com.coyotes.springboot.app.models.entity.Contacto
```

Asi mismo si yo por la misma pagina deseo agregar datos a la pagina web no me manda nada no se si son por los dropdown o algo asi..

Este es el Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head th:replace="layout/layout :: head">
<title th:text="${titulo}"></title>
</head>
<body>

    <header th:replace="layout/layout :: header"></header>
    <div class="container py-4">

        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-header" th:text="${titulo}"></div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a th:href="@{/}" class="btn btn-light btn-xs"
                        th:utext="#{text.global.volver}">&laquo; Volver</a> <a
                        sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-xs float-right " th:href="@{/listac}">Contactantes</a>
                </h4>

                <div th:object="${contacto}" th:remove="tag">
                    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="alert alert-danger"
                        role="alert">
                        <li th:each="err:${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <form th:action="@{/formc}" th:object="${contacto}" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="motivo" th:text="#{text.contacto.motivo.titulo}">Motivo</label>
                        <select id="motivo" class="form-control">
                            <option selected th:text="#{text.contacto.motivo.elige}">Elige..</option>
                            <option value="CP" th:text="#{text.contacto.motivo.comen}">Comentario
                                o pregunta</option>
                            <option value="PQ" th:text="#{text.contacto.motivo.queja}">Problema
                                o queja</option>
                        </select><small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('motivo')}" th:errors="*{motivo}"></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="tema" th:text="#{text.contacto.tema.titulo}">Tema</label>
                        <select id="tema" class="form-control">
                            <option selected th:text="#{text.contacto.tema.selecciona}">Selecciona
                                el tema..</option>
                            <option value="AClientes"
                                th:text="#{text.contacto.tema.atencion}">Atencion al
                                Cliente</option>
                            <option value="Expor"
                                th:text="#{text.contacto.tema.exportaciones}">Exportaciones</option>
                            <option value="Comer" th:text="#{text.contacto.tema.comercial}">Comercial</option>
                            <option value="Venta"
                                th:text="#{text.practicas.departamento.ventas}">Ventas</option>
                            <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
                        </select><small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tema')}" th:errors="*{tema}"></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="comentarios" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label"
                            th:text="#{text.contacto.comentario}">Comentarios</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{comentarios}"
                                th:errorclass="'form-control alert-danger'" /> <small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('comentarios')}"
                                th:errors="*{comentarios}"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                            th:text="#{text.practicas.nombre}">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" class="form-control"
                                th:errorclass="'form-control alert-danger'" /> <small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                            th:text="#{text.practicas.telefono}">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{telefono}" class="form-control"
                                th:errorclass="'form-control alert-danger'" /> <small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('telefono')}" th:errors="*{telefono}"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                            th:text="#{text.practicas.email}">Correo</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control"
                                th:errorclass="'form-control alert-danger'" /> <small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="estado" th:text="#{text.contacto.estado.titulo}">Estado</label>
                        <select id="estado" class="form-control">
                            <option selected th:text="#{text.contacto.estado.elige}">Elige..</option>
                            <option value="Aguascalientes">Aguascalientes</option>
                            <option value="Baja California">Baja California</option>
                            <option value="Baja California Sur">Baja California Sur</option>
                            <option value="Campeche">Campeche</option>
                            <option value="Chiapas">Chiapas</option>
                            <option value="Chihuahua">Chihuahua</option>
                            <option value="Coahuila">Coahuila</option>
                            <option value="Colima">Colima</option>
                            <option value="CDMX">Cuidad de Mexico</option>
                            <option value="Durango">Durango</option>
                            <option value="Guanajuato">Guanajuato</option>
                            <option value="Guerrero">Guerrero</option>
                            <option value="Hidalgo">Hidalgo</option>
                            <option value="Jalisco">Jalisco</option>
                            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="Michoacan">Michoacan</option>
                            <option value="Morelos">Morelos</option>
                            <option value="Nayarit">Nayarit</option>
                            <option value="Nuevo Leon">Nuevo Leon</option>
                            <option value="Oaxaca">Oaxaca</option>
                            <option value="Puebla">Puebla</option>
                            <option value="Queretaro">Queretaro</option>
                            <option value="Quintana Roo">Quintana Roo</option>
                            <option value="San Luis">San Luis Potosi</option>
                            <option value="Sinaloa">Sinaloa</option>
                            <option value="Sonora">Sonora</option>
                            <option value="Tabasco">Tabasco</option>
                            <option value="Tamaulipas">Tamaulipas</option>
                            <option value="Tlaxcala">Tlaxcala</option>
                            <option value="Veracruz">Veracruz</option>
                            <option value="Yucatan">Yucatan</option>
                            <option value="Zacatecas">Zacatecas</option>
                        </select><small
                                class="form-text text-danger"
                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('estado')}" th:errors="*{estado}"></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="submit" th:text="#{text.contacto.form.enviar}"
                                class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer th:replace="layout/layout :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Y el controlador lo unico que hace es el guardar poder ver, editar y eliminar segun sea el caso y algunos solamente siendo Administradores..

Pero el error mas que nada es en Guardar y como me pide un get para lo que son los dropdown necesito usar 2 guardar, y estoy pensando que probablemente es por eso..

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @GetMapping(value = "/formc")
    public String guardar(@Valid Contacto contacto, BindingResult result, Model model,
             RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status, Locale locale) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("titulo", messageSource.getMessage("text.contacto.form.titulo", null, locale));
            return "formc";
        }

        String mensajeFlash = (contacto.getId() != null) ? messageSource.getMessage("text.contacto.flash.editar.success", null, locale) : messageSource.getMessage("text.practicas.flash.guardar.success", null, locale);


        status.setComplete();
        flash.addFlashAttribute("success", mensajeFlash);
        return "redirect:formc";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value="/formc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String guardar2( @Valid Contacto contacto, BindingResult result, Model model,
             RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status, Locale locale) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("titulo", messageSource.getMessage("text.contacto.form.titulo", null, locale));
            return "formc";
        }

        String mensajeFlash = (contacto.getId() != null) ? messageSource.getMessage("text.contacto.flash.editar.success", null, locale) : messageSource.getMessage("text.practicas.flash.guardar.success", null, locale);

        contactoService.save(contacto);
        status.setComplete();
        flash.addFlashAttribute("success", mensajeFlash);
        return "redirect:formc";
    }
```

Service

```
 @Service
public class ContactoServiceImp implements IContactoService{

    @Autowired
    private IContactoDao contactoDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Contacto contacto) {
        contactoDao.save(contacto);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Contacto> findAll() {
        return (List<Contacto>) contactoDao.findAll();  
        }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Contacto findOne(Long id) {
        return contactoDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long id) {
        contactoDao.deleteById(id);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Page<Contacto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return  contactoDao.findAll(pageable);
    }

}
```

Interface Service

```
public interface IContactoService {

    public List<Contacto> findAll();

    public void save(Contacto contacto);

    public Page<Contacto> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    public Contacto findOne(Long id);

    public void delete(Long id);

}
```

Entity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="contacto")
public class Contacto implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String motivo;

    @NotEmpty
    private String tema;

    @NotEmpty
    private String comentarios;

    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 10)
    private String telefono;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String estado;

    /*@NotNull
    @Column(name = "create_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createAt;*/


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getMotivo() {
        return motivo;
    }


    public void setMotivo(String motivo) {
        this.motivo = motivo;
    }


    public String getTema() {
        return tema;
    }


    public void setTema(String tema) {
        this.tema = tema;
    }


    public String getComentarios() {
        return comentarios;
    }


    public void setComentarios(String comentarios) {
        this.comentarios = comentarios;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }


    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }


    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }


    /*public Date getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }


    public void setCreateAt(Date createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }*/


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

y el modelDao

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.coyotes.springboot.app.models.entity.Contacto;

public interface IContactoDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contacto, Long>{

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar porque tengo muchisimo con este problema y no se que mas hacer..